# Handler for static file Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http

New to App Engine. I need to verify my website with google webmaster.

Here's what I've added to app.yaml

```
handlers:

- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img

- url: /google6432717e3cdee901.html
  static_files: /google6432717e3cdee901.html
  upload: /google6432717e3cdee901.html
```

However visiting `site.com/google6432717e3cdee901.html`  gives me a 404 error.

How do I fix my handlers so I can visit the file and get verified?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: provide your entire app.yaml file data if possible

Comment: Did you get any error while updating your app? I would say that you need to remove the leading slash from the static_files and upload.

Answer (score 3):

Don't include the leading `/` in the `static_files` and `upload` directives (unless the files really are at the root of your filesystem, which is probably a Bad Idea).