# Simple edit to app.yaml file to access html file

Tags: regex, google-app-engine

I want to be able to (statically) access the specific file google.html in my root directory.

I am having trouble editing the app.yaml file to make this work as I keep getting 404 errors.

Here's what I am currently doing

```
- url: /(google\.html)
  static_files: /\1
  upload: /(google\.html)
```

I've also tried

```
    - url: /google.html
      static_files: google.html
      upload: /google.html
```

(This is added before all other handlers)
What should it be instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handler for static file Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682989/handler-for-static-file-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a google.html file (lower case file) in the root of your project.
Please post your directory structure in case you think you have it.

Comment: The file is at /google.html ,  In fact the second version without any regex groupings works on my local machine but does not work when deployed.

Comment: The production servers are case sensitive, check that the file name is lower case.

Comment: The file is definitely lower case and I am able to visit it on my local server. This is super frustrating :(

Comment: I would expect the second version to work.  Did you double check that the new instance was running properly after you deployed, and that you're hitting the right app version?

Comment: it says im hitting the right version and that the instance is running properly (the app itself works fine..i just can't access that file)..what other debugging can i do?

Comment: please post a screenshot of your project layout.

Comment: finally solved the problem simply by moving the file from the root to a sub-directory "static" and just mapping the url handler accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It appears that app engine didn't like the static file in the root directory. Moving the google.html file to /static solved the problem.

So the handler becomes:

```
- url: /google.html
  static_files: static/google.html
  upload: static/google.html
```

This way the endpoint is still / even though the file itself is in the static directory.